# Idea not recognizing thrift types from another module in same gradle project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, thrift

I have the following project structure

```
datatypes/
  build.gradle
  src/main/thrift/service.thrift
service/
  build.gradle
  /src/main/java/ServiceImpl.java
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

I am using yodle/gradle as a gradle plugin to generate java sources from thrift and compiling those. The sources and jar files are being generated in `datatypes` as expected.

in `service/build.gradle`, I have a dependency defined as:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':datatypes')
}
```

Running `gradle build` works perfectly fine; my only issue is while working in idea. After importing this as gradle module, I can't get the types defined in thrift to be recognized in `ServiceImpl.java`.

How do I get idea to include the jar in `datatypes/build/libs/` as dependency for `service`?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at their [documentation](https://github.com/yodle/griddle#interaction-with-ideaeclipse-plugins) specifically regarding IDE integration?

Comment: That works (using idea properties to change include/exclude folders for sources), but I want a solution which doesn't make me touch the idea settings. Because for a shared project, everyone using idea will have to do this everytime they import this project.

Comment: @Mark I just realized from the documentation that putting generated source in build/ folder doesn't make sense, so implemented the solution as below. Thanks!

Comment: That will work, but putting generated source in your main source directory is typically discourages. Firstly, your are polluting a version controlled directory with build artifacts which then has to be ignored. Second, it can make doing a clean problematic, since generated source is intermixed with static source. Instead, all build artifacts (to included generated source) should go in your build directory. You should then configure your [source sets](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:source_sets) to add the generated source directory.

Comment: I tried adding a path in build/ to source sets, and while that works for gradle build on the command line, idea still doesn't recognize that. I understand what you are saying. What I did do, however, is add /gen-java to .gitignore, which helps with version control.

Answer (score 0):

The issue really is that the default thrift generated java source path set by `yodle/griddle` plugin is inside the `build/` folder. I just added the following in my `datatypes/build.gradle`

```
thriftGenDir = 'src/main'
```

and now the java code is generated in `src/main/gen-java` which is picked up as source for `dataypes` by idea, and uses it to define types for anyone who depends on `datatypes`.